# Need help figuring out how to organise a system to run a stepper motor at low speed without Steps-skipping

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor, torque, speed, stepper-driver

TL;DR : How to prevent step-skipping with a NEMA gearbox motor at low speed.

Edit: following @glen_geek comment, removing the load on the system seems to remove the problem, hinting at inertia and torque as the main issue.

I am in the process of creating a system in which I want an object to turn on a plate and to show a letter depending on the angle of the rotation. The object is quite heavy hence the rotation should be quite slow, this is why I took a Planetary Gearbox NEMA Stepper.

My system consists in:

- An Arduino Uno
- [A NEMA Stepper Motor](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B077YXF759?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details)
- [A A4988 Driver](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B083V59HTB?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details)
- Some wires
- 2 Iron plates
- [A ball bearing element in between the Iron plates](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B0B98YSRQS?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details)
- Screws to fit everything together.

This is the code I ended up with:

```
// Define stepper motor connections and steps per revolution:
#define dirPin 6
#define stepPin 7
#define stepsPerRevolution 5373
int degree_init = 1;

int mouvement=0;

// create a mapping between letters and degrees
int letterToDegree[33] ;
int degree;
// function to map letters to degrees
int mapLetterToDegree(char letter) {
  if (letter=='.'){
    return letterToDegree[27];
  }
  else if (letter==':'){
    return letterToDegree[28];
  }
  else if (letter=="\'"){
    return letterToDegree[29];
  }
  else if (letter==' '){
    return letterToDegree[30];
  }
  else {
  int letterIndex = letter - 'A'; // get the index of the letter in the alphabet
  return letterToDegree[letterIndex]; // return the degree associated with that letter
  }
}

void setup() {
  // Declare pins as output:
  pinMode(stepPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dirPin, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600); 
    for (int i = 0; i < 33; i++){
    letterToDegree[i]= degree_init;
    degree_init=degree_init+10;
  }
}

void loop() {
  int p= NULL;
  // Set the spinning direction clockwise:
  digitalWrite(dirPin, HIGH);
  String input= "NOW THE NOW THE AAAAA";
  // loop through the letters
  for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    // get the degree for each letter
    degree = mapLetterToDegree(input[i]);
    Serial.print("Letter: ");
    Serial.print(input[i]);
    Serial.print(" Degrees: ");
    Serial.println(degree);
    // wait for the movement to complete
    delay(1000);
 
  int p_new= map(degree,0,360,0,5373);
  Serial.print(" position: ");
  Serial.println(p_new);
  if (p!=NULL){
    mouvement=p_new-p;
    p=p_new;
  Serial.print(" mouvement: ");
  Serial.println(mouvement);
  }
  else{
    p = p_new;
  }
  if (mouvement<0){
    digitalWrite(dirPin, LOW);
    mouvement=abs(mouvement);
    Serial.println("change de direction");
  }
  Serial.print(" stepper: ");
  Serial.println(mouvement);

  // Spin the stepper motor 1 revolution slowly:
  for (int i = 0; i < mouvement; i++) {
    // These four lines result in 1 step:
    digitalWrite(stepPin, HIGH);
    delay(20);
    digitalWrite(stepPin, LOW);
    delay(20);
  }
 
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(dirPin, HIGH);
}
}
```

I tried following [this tutorial](https://www.makerguides.com/a4988-stepper-motor-driver-arduino-tutorial/) and it works in broad terms **but sometimes the motor skips steps, especially when changing direction.**

I can't seem to understand how torque works within this system and how to minimise the stress I put on the motor.
My hypothesis is that since the system is at equilibrium and the friction is minimised due to the ball bearing, there should be no need for a lot of power from the motor, and that this motor should suffice.

My hypothesis of why steps are skipped:

- Too high a speed for the motor
- Not enough torque power supplied
- Not good enough electricity supply to the motor.

I am not sure how to go about and test these hypothesis and if those are correct.
I am also having a lot of trouble understanding the relationship between the time delay in the code and the movement of the motor.

Especially this bit:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < mouvement; i++) {
    // These four lines result in 1 step:
    digitalWrite(stepPin, HIGH);
    delay(20);
    digitalWrite(stepPin, LOW);
    delay(20);
  }
```

Is it ok to change them as I did? do they need to be symetrical (same delay for high and low)?

I am also looking for an explanation of how to apply acceleration and decceleration algorithms for stepper motor, even though I am not sure it makes sense at this speed.

**My questions are:**

- How to calculate the best speed for such a system and how to implement it?
- Is there need for acceleration/ decceleration?
- Does microstepping makes sense when using a gearbox?
- Are there some obvious flaws in my system/ code that I am missing out?

NOTE: This is a duplicate of [this question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/92139/need-help-figuring-out-how-to-organise-a-system-to-run-a-stepper-motor-at-low-sp) on arduino stackexchange as I did not know which one it fit best

[image: Arduino and Driver]
[image: stepper and ball bearing plate]
[image: Behaviour description]
[image: System description]

Comment: Un-load all that mass (plate, bearings)  from the motor's shaft, then test again for missed steps. Does that pass?

Comment: After doing this type of stuff for years and years, I've decided that all my position systems shall never be open loop (as yours is).  Add a position encoder for feedback, limit (or "zero") switch(es), and preferably. a hardware controller that supports encoder feedback input.  Then you'll sleep happy.

Comment: *Is there need for acceleration/ decceleration?* Yes. I wrote my own for MSP430 MCU using what I learned here: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/doc8017.pdf For Arduino, you should be able to find accel/decel code.

Comment: @glen_geek  It seems to remove the problem when unloaded.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen Do you have any advice when it comes to this type of hardware? I am a bit lost to what I should use.

Comment: "sometimes the motor skips steps, especially when changing direction." - That indicates a mechanical problem. The first suspect should be the gearbox. You don't know how much hysteresis it has.  A quick fix would be to make the motor only rotate in one direction. I'm also curious about your gear ratio. From the stepsPerRevolution 5373 it would seem to be something weird, and you should probably explain that one. If that's a standard NEMA stepper, the shaft is 200 step/rev. Then 5374 doesn't give a reasonable gear ratio. How did you derive your number?

Comment: "Do you have any advice when it comes to this type of hardware?"  Find a stepper controller (they come at all price-points from $10's to $1000's), with encoder feedback input.  The controller will also typically handle limit, or zero inputs, as well as take care of accel and decel.  The controller most often has the motor driver stage as well - your motor would connect directly to it.  Perhaps you can find cheaper controllers without the driver stage, and use your current one.  It's off-topic here (and frowned upon) to make product suggestions.  Arduino could talk to it via serial (or other).

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Thanks for the comment. The motor-gearbox info I found said that the steps were equal to 0.067 degrees, I just divided 360 by this number. It seems to work fine in terms of rotation. 
Here are the specs in terms of torque:
*Max.Permissible Torque: 3Nm(425oz.in)
*Moment Permissible Torque: 5Nm(708oz.in)

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen Thanks for the info, I'll try to find one fitting your description.

Comment: The driver does the actual steps - the step signal just tells it when to step. Probably when you write HIGH it triggers the step. The only reason to write LOW is so that you can write HIGH again. The driver doesn't really care when you write LOW.

Comment: The breadboard wiring is too sloppy (thin an long wires) for the motor current involved. Does your supply deliver enough current? I can not see any big capacitor supporting your supply. You should look either for a library that includes accelleration and decelleration or choose a driver that has an internal movement machine like L6470 (the demo boards from st.com are quite cheap). Swapping directions needs first to decellerate to zero and then to accellerate again. The L6470 does all that for you, is a great device, I've used it often.

Comment: @Guillaume_slize - If you assume .067 should actually be .06666666... , then the step count is 5400 steps per revolution, and a 200 step motor implies a gear ratio of 27:1. Which works just fine as 3 3:1 stages in series. Three stages also gives a lot of opportunity for mechanical slop. If you're going to use this motor, I suggest you only drive it in one direction.